# Formatting an Excel date without space between elements

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to format a Date in Excel (Office 2010 for what matters) in the following format:
`<week day><day>/<month>` (e.g. "Wednesday14/3").

I came up with the format `dddd_dd/m` that gives "Wednesday 14/3" but I don't know how to remove the space between the week day and the day.

Any idea?

Thanks

---

PS: for those who wonder such an ugly format, it is actually because I use the format for a date in Chinese `[$-804]dddd_dd/m` that returns "星期三 14/3". Slightly more appealing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the asterisk works. Try if `dddd*dd/m` works for you, it does it for me.

Comment: Nice. I couldn't figure this out.

Comment: @Raystafarian: I didn't know about it either, i just tried which of the special chars that other formats used resulted in the desired outcome. :-)